# NearZeroVar in R returning percentUnique > 0 for constant features?

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm struggling a bit with NearZeroVar feature in r (caret).

See the results below in the attached image.

What strikies me is that I have variables with just a single values throughout all the samples:

- `TotalNumberOfJudgements`
- `TotalMonthlyInstallments`

See below also a freq function of the column.

This is further confirmed by the `freqRation = 0` for these variable.

How is then the `percentUnique` calculated - why does the function returns 2.7% when there's no variance at all?

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`percentUnique` means the number of unique entries over the total entries. Using an example:

```
library(caret)
mtcars$newVar1 = 1
mtcars$newVar2 = c(1,rep(2,nrow(mtcars)-1))

nearZeroVar(mtcars,saveMetrics=TRUE)
        freqRatio percentUnique zeroVar   nzv
mpg      1.000000        78.125   FALSE FALSE
cyl      1.272727         9.375   FALSE FALSE
disp     1.500000        84.375   FALSE FALSE
hp       1.000000        68.750   FALSE FALSE
drat     1.000000        68.750   FALSE FALSE
wt       1.500000        90.625   FALSE FALSE
qsec     1.000000        93.750   FALSE FALSE
vs       1.285714         6.250   FALSE FALSE
am       1.461538         6.250   FALSE FALSE
gear     1.250000         9.375   FALSE FALSE
carb     1.000000        18.750   FALSE FALSE
newVar1  0.000000         3.125    TRUE  TRUE
newVar2 31.000000         6.250   FALSE  TRUE
```

For newVar1, we have only 1 unique value like you have, and therefore you get:

```
1/nrow(mtcars)
[1] 0.03125
```

Which is `3.125` percent. Likewise, newVar2 has 2 unique values, so you get:

```
length(unique(mtcars$newVar2))/nrow(mtcars)
[1] 0.0625
```

Comment: I admire the way you put the answer, simple, streightforward.